# While using Navigation Drawer CollapsingToolbarLayout with ImageView toolbar doesn't show

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my android app I have an activity with navigation drawer. I am also using CollapsingToolbarLayout with ImageView inside of it because would also like to have and image as a background of the toolbar that would collapse after scroll. 
Now the image displays and colapse just well but the toolbar is not displayed. I can't see button to open navigation drawer or menu button. Here are my layout files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/navigation_view_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_color"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="40dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/activity_description_header"
            layout="@layout/fragment_edit_header"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_edit_header.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">        

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src = "@drawable/image"/>

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ncrypted.redfox.Activities.HomeClass">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBar_hotel_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_hotel_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/redfox"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollNestedData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      // add here your other controls 


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**use this theme**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@mipmap/ic_left_back</item>-->
</style>
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: Using your layout I can see the toolbar now but the ImageView is underneath it and not in the background

Comment: @matip can you provide image which type of layout you want

Comment: I would like something like this. Image in the background of the toolbar after scrolling down. http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/collapsing-toolbar-layout.gif

Comment: Most Welcome @matip